# In which directories can "nobody" user write?

Tags: permissions, user-management

In which directories can the `nobody` user write in a standard, out-of-the-box Ubuntu distribution?

I already know about `/tmp` which is `drwxrwxrwt`, but are there any other places by default where any user can write?

Comment: `/var/tmp`, for one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Running a check on my system lists:

```
$ sudo find / -xdev -type d \( \( -user nobody -o -group nogroup \) -o -perm -777 \)
/tmp
/tmp/.X11-unix
/tmp/.ICE-unix
/var/tmp
/var/metrics
/var/spool/samba
/var/crash
```

Of these, I imagine `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, and `/var/crash` to be present on all Ubuntu installations, since they are listed in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html). The two directories inside `/tmp` are, I think, session-based directories, so they can be ignored. I don't think `/var/spool/samba` would be present on a fresh Ubuntu system, which leaves `/var/metrics`. I'm not sure what that directory is for.

A note on the `find` command:

- `-xdev` excludes other filesystems (so I can skip `/proc`, `/sys`, my home directory, etc.)
- `-type d` restricts the check to directories
- `\( -user nobody -o -group nogroup \)` - either the owner should be `nobody`, or the `group` should be `nogroup`. We use the brackets to group this condition, and check for the other possibility, that
- `-perm -777` - everyone has all permissions, again joined using an OR (`-o`). Instead of `-perm -777`, one could simply use `-perm -2` as Random832 suggests, to check write permission to others.

Comment: I would really like to have some ideas on how the find command forms altogether ;)

Comment: @heemayl I added an explanation of the `find` command I used.

Comment: shouldn't this be -perm -002? That way you aren't checking everyone to have every permission, just world-write permission

Comment: @Random832 `-perm -2` added one more to the list, `/var/lib/php5`, which has the rather surprising mode `rwx-wx-wt`. Good catch!

Comment: @muru IIRC this means anyone can create files in the directory, and can open files that they know exist, but cannot list the contents.

Comment: @Random832 indeed.